# How to support object rest spreading highlight in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

```
{
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
  ...{c: 5}
}
```

It is called [object rest spreading](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).
How could i make vs-code to support this syntax?
At this moment it just get a syntax warning in that line

Comment: Have you seen [**this issue**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1974)?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed since at least VSCode 1.11 I believe. Please try using the current version of VSCode